# modifying the elements nested lists in python

Tags: python, nested-lists

can anyone explain what's happening behind this? I tried to search for similar behavior but most of the questions on iterating nested lists

```
r1=[0 for i in range(3)]
result=[r1 for j in range(3)]
result[0][0]=4 # it will edit all the 0th elements of the sublists
print(result)

r1=[0 for i in range(3)]
result=[r1 for j in range(3)]
result[1][0]=4 # it will edit all the 0th elements of the sublists
print(result)

r1=[0 for i in range(3)]
result=[r1 for j in range(3)]
result[0][1]=4 # it will edit all the 1st elements of the sublists
print(result)

result = [[0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]
result[0][0]=4
print(result) # it will edit only the first element of first sublist
```

the output is

```
[[4, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0]]
[[4, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0], [4, 0, 0]]
[[0, 4, 0], [0, 4, 0], [0, 4, 0]]
[[4, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Do `print([id(x) for x in result])` and all should become clear...

Comment: Try also `result = [r1.copy() for j in range(3)]` - note the `copy` here, and also look at the IDs as shown above...

Comment: As your list is made of ints, you can also just do `result = [r1[:] for j in range(3)]`. Or, just get rid of `r1` completely: `result = [[0 for i in range(3)] for j in range(3)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from how you construct your nested list. The following:

```py
r1=[0 for i in range(3)]
result=[r1 for j in range(3)]
```

Creates a list of 3 `r1`. And not a list of 3 different lists which is why, when you modify any of `result[j]` it modifies `r1` and therefore all others `result[j]`. As pointed out by others, that's the exact same problem as [described here, with a different expression: `result = [r1] * 3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly?noredirect=1&lq=1)

On the other hand, on your last test you create what you expect, a list of 3 distinct lists:

```py
result = [[0 for x in range(3)] for y in range(3)]
```

You can do the same using `r1`:

```py
result = [[x for x in r1] for y in range(3)]
```

Here the inner "loop" simply copy the elements of `r1` into a new (distinct) list:

```py
r1 = [0 for i in range(3)]
result = [[x for x in r1] for y in range(3)]
result[0][0] = 4
print(result)
```

Prints:

```py
[[4, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
```

You can observe the original problem in this simpler example where modifications on `r1` are also impacting `r2`:

```py
r1 = [0 for i in range(3)]
r2 = r1 
r1[0] = 4
print(r2)
```

The reason behind this behaviour is simply that `r1` and `r2` are two names for the same object. When we write `r1[0] = 4` we don't change the value of `r1` we change the value of the list `r1` refers to (or
points to* if you prefer). This is not specific to python and any data structure that can be modified "in-place" will suffer this "problem" (I suggested reading about mutable vs. immutable data structure to better understand what's going on here).

Comment: I suggest that `r1.copy()` is a clearer way to write your inner list comprehension, but agreed. *[edit to comment: I see that this requires python 3 though]*

Comment: I was simply suggesting using the same form, but to be honest I think I would use the list comprehension in practice too. Not sure what the majority of people would do, or what the standard is. I would read both without problem tho.

Comment: I agree with the list-comp, I would just do `result = [[0 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]` and get rid of `r1` altogether...

Comment: I prefer to leave the OP code as it is and only modify what is required to be modified. But I agree that this is quite standard to name unused variables `_`. And I most often use that form too in my code. Maybe `r1` is not something we have control over, that's why I prefer not too guess and leave it like it is.